# accessing an iis localhost path from another computer on the network

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have a web application project in visual studio 2015. and i built it on Local iis with http://localhost/WebApplication1 URL. i can access to the project from my computer with above url but i can not access from another computer that i directly connected it to this.

I check these:

```
1.I can share folders from these computers.
2.I make a rule in firewall for port 80 inbound
3.I checked vs debug remote allowed in firewall
4.I checked "ping localhost" and it received ping
```

I use windows 10 with iis express 6

Comment: you can use http://[machinename]/WebApplication1 or http://[IP_of_machine]/WebApplication1

Comment: Solved the same problem for me, too, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS Express was primarily designed to only process local requests for debug and development purposes. Though one can *open it up* and provide external requests with your site with a few tweaks.

In the file `applicationhost.config` which resides at `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config` change your `localhost` to `*` or even the name of your machine.

Otherwise why not install IIS which allows for more tweaking of the site than express?

[How to Install IIS on Windows 8 or Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/)

Comment: first i tried iis virtual directory to put my project in it.i set Sitename:Webapp, physical path:Where the project is, type:http, IP address: All Unassigned, port:80, Host name:localhost but i when i brows the webapp it doesn't show anything! whats the problem?

Comment: Did you restart it all?

Comment: Yes. I restart it. but i just face with an empty page when i click Brows localhost on *:80 (http) in the right pane

Comment: This is a vague answer that why the downvote. Please say where to change localhost to * exactly. I've found only one instance of localhost in the mentioned filed and changed it but nothing worked.

Comment: You most likely have a different issue, therefore one could not guess at what would work in *your situation*. You should post your own question with the relevant points provided and a minimally reproducible example.