# I can't call API from another PC at the same network

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, networking, lan

I connected two laptops together with a wi-fi modem.

- Laptop1 got the IP 192.168.0.20
- Laptop2 got the IP 192.168.0.21

I launched an ASP.Net Core web application on Laptop2 on port 44382.
I turned off both laptops' firewalls.

The result of `ping 192.168.0.20` from laptop2
[image: Ping 0.21 from 0.20]

The result of `ping 192.168.0.21` from laptop1
[image: Ping 0.20 from 0.21]

When I call my API from the laptop2(localhost) there is no problem and I see the result
[image: My API call]

The problem is when I call API from laptop1(another laptop), after a long time I see this
[image]

I can't find what my problem is.

Comment: port should be open as well

Comment: What web server are you running?  It's possible to listen on only on the local loopback IP address, and not on your network IP address.  Can you get to http://192.168.0.21:... from Laptop2?  In Powershell you can run `[System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners()` to list the listining IP, Port pairs.  `0.0.0.0` means All IPs.

Comment: If you're using IIS Express, have a look at all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/how-to-enable-external-request-in-iis-express) but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971694/729541) in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely using IIS Express, which doesn't automatically bind everything the way you need for remote access. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157264/accessing-an-iis-localhost-path-from-another-computer-on-the-network) breaks down what you'll need to accomplish that fairly well, but you may just want to look at installing IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure door 44382 is open in the firewall.

[Create new rule in/out for port here (advanced configs of firewall)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YPTV.png)